# How do you open a new window in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am creating a Kinect application and want to open a new window called 'Help' from the 'MainWindow.xaml.cs' file.

I tried using the following code:

```
// The commented code is what I have tried.
public static void ThreadProc()
{
     // Window Help = new Window();
     //Application.Run(new Window(Help);    

     Application.Run(new Form()); 
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ThreadProc));

    t.Start();
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to show this window on a separate thread? You can do that, but it's rare to need to.

Comment: @Joshua - If you show a Window on another Thread please understand that it will not be a UI Thread. Please refer to here: http://www.codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Opening-WPF-Windows-on-a-new-thread.aspx for a complete tutorial

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Showing a window just requires a call to its `Show` method.

However, keeping an application running requires a call to `Application.Run`.  If you pass this method a form, it'll call `Show` for you.

However, if you already have a running application, you can just do something like `new MyForm().Show()`.

I strongly suspect you don't need to create a new thread and `Application` for your new window.  Can't you just use:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Form().Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I was trying to over complicate things.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you run the application there but usually you open a window by creating an instance and [showing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show.aspx) it.

```
var window = new Help(); // Help being the help window class
window.Show();
```

Also as this on the background thread it may cause trouble in terms of inter-control communication. Usually you will want to create and access UI-elements on the UI thread only. To move any operation to the UI-thread you can use the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) of the UI-thread. See also:  [Threading Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you need your own, just add to the project a new form, or create your own from the stratch and call

```
myForm.Show()
```